Explicit Data of Homotopy Fixed Points in Lurie's TFT
Lurie's classification theorem [1, Theorem 2.4.26] classifies fully extended
tfts for $G$-manifolds in terms of homotopy fixed points:

Let $C$ be a symmetric monoidal $(\infty, n)$-category with duals, and let $\chi : G \to O(n)$ be a continuous group homomorphism. There is a canonical equivalence of $(\infty, n)$-categories $Fun^\otimes(Bord^G_n, C) \to (C^\sim)^{hG}$. In particular, $Fun^\otimes(Bord^G_n , C)$ is an $\infty$-groupoid.

Then the paper goes on, without detailed arguments, claiming how $(C^\sim)^{hG}$ looks like for small groups like $G = SO(2)$ (see
Calabi-Yau objects, [1, Remark 4.2.7]). I wish to fill in this gap in my
understanding.
By definition, for a infinity groupoid $X$ admitting a $G$-action, $$X^{hG} :=
Map_G(EG, X).$$ However, I don't see how you can computer/describe $X^{hG}$
explicitly using this definition, as $EG$ is complicated as a topological space.
I'd like to see how it can be described in terms of explicit data: an object
$x$ in $X$, some $k$-morphisms in $X$ (for each $k$), and some conditions that
they satisfy.
In particular, I'd like to see why the nontrivial homotopy information in $BG$
complicate the issue (e.g. $G=SO(2)$ [2][3], $G = SO(3)$ [3]), and a sketch of
why Calabi-Yau objects are exactly the $SO(2)$ homotopy fixed points.

[1] On the Classification of Topological Field Theories - Jacob Lurie
[2] Answer by C. Schommer-Pries
[3] Discussions in Dualizable tensor categories
Christopher L. Douglas, Christopher Schommer-Pries, Noah Snyder

